# Laravel ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap, error404

Estoy investigando el problema ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Y de todas las respuestas encontradas sobre el tema ninguna me solventa el problema.

Al acceder en mi localhost:8000 algunas funcionalidades no funcionaban. Me fije en la consola y veo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriomente revisé el archivo de jquery propio de Bootstrap:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js

Y al acceder a esta dirección me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé en otros navegadores, mismo problema. Accedí a producción lo mismo.

Borré las cookies, limpié la pc, temporales y todo lo que se pueda realizar de limpieza.

Cambié el archivo jquery slim por otro CDN y descargue también uno, el error persiste.

Como puedo identificar el problema?

Comment: Verifica que el nombre de las rutas no sea igual al nombre de tus funciones, me ha pasado eso cuando pongo el mismo nombre de la ruta a la función

Comment: No tiene que ver con JQuery. Estás configurando algún enrutamiento o redirección que se está llamando a sí mismo en un ciclo infinito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia el cdn que trae por defecto el template starter de Bootstrap.

Por defecto:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Por este:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Espero que te sirva!!!

Comment: Si lo que hice fue cambiar el cdn pero lo descargue directamente y ahí si me anduvo!! Gracias Ramiro!!